# Hover Details on related lists

Tags: page-layout, related-list, user-interface

From what i found the salesforce hover details feature (pop up to show details of object on another objects layout)(User Interface > Enable Hover Details) does not work on related lists. 
It works only on parent objects
Form my prospective i can't understand way it does not also work on related list. Its the same functionality 
Does anyone have any ideas on how to implement this feature or one like it ?
I could implement it with JavaScript and a js ui framework but was hoping there was a more saleforces oriented way to do it

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

Setup > Customize > Enable Related List Hover Links

Answer (score 0):

I think this feature is only available Lookup Fields (shown on Page Layout).

The related lists are do not display Lookup Fields the same as page layout, so it cannot display a pop-up.